# I used template to add two number for any kind of data types, but it did not work out

Tags: c++

What changes should be made to take any kind of data types?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
T add(T n1, T n2)
{
    T res;
    res = (n1 + n2);
    return res;
}
int main()
{
    double x, y;
    cout << "Enter first number : "; cin >> x;
    cout << "Enter second number : "; cin >> y;
    cout << add(x, y);
}
```

Comment: How did it not "work out"?  What is wrong with it?

Comment: I don't see the problem. It should work ok. https://ideone.com/I9o18S

Comment: Your template function is correct - what problem are you having?

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to do things like add a `short` to an `int`? Or a `float` and a `double` and have it Do The Right Thing?

Comment: Not the problem, but the code in the template is noisy. `return n1+ n2;` will work just as well.

Comment: @Andy M if user input 4.756, it just takes 4

Comment: Enter first number : 5.6
Enter second number : 5 . This is what happen when user input 5.6, it directly set 5 for second number and does not add them

Comment: @H.Rahman I cannot [reproduce](http://ideone.com/NHZpr3) the problem you claim (check the link).

Comment: @H.Rahman [Same for your second example](http://ideone.com/hSYabh)

Comment: @H.Rahman In case you are running that from your debugger, try `cout << add(x, y) << endl;`. The output may be simply not flushed when you reach your breakpoint at the end.

Comment: so in main () i use double data types which handles any data types for a template ()

Comment: @H.Rahman I don't get your latest comment? Did you try what I advised you?

Comment: yes, it worked. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @Shaktal, how do i do that? Add a short and int, float and double

Answer (score 2):

You asked in a comment how you can add a short and an int, or a float and a double; so here is an example of how to do this in C++11 and C++14.

**C++11:**

```
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto add( T t, U u ) -> decltype(t + u)
{
    return t + u;
}
```

**C++14:**

```
template <typename T, typename U>
constexpr auto add( T t, U u )
{
    return t + u;
}
```

This will allow you to do things like:

```
short a = 31;
long long b = 1234;
std::cout << add(a,b) << '\n';
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You should use the comment section under the question to ask for clarification of the OP's needs.

Answer (score 0):

may be

```
cout << add<double>(x, y);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

add is a template method must be declared with a type :  add(args)